# How to only compress pdf images without changing fonts with GhostScript?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

We are using GhostScript to compress PDF files but, using the following parameters, it ends up changing some fonts (Bookman Old Style, Garamond and Lucida Console)

```
-dSAFER
-dBATCH
-dNOPAUSE
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite
-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook
-dCompressPages=false \ -dCompressFonts=false \ -dEmbedAllFonts=false \ -dSubsetFonts=false \ -dDownsampleColorImages=true \ -dDownsampleGrayImages=true \ -dDownsampleMonoImages=true \ -dColorImageResolution=200 \ -dGrayImageResolution=200 \ -dMonoImageResolution=200 \ -sOutputFile=<filename>
-f
```

Here you can access the [before](https://sourceforge.net/p/ghostscript/discussion/5451/thread/17e19a54/ca48/attachment/original.pdf) and [after](https://sourceforge.net/p/ghostscript/discussion/5451/thread/17e19a54/ca48/attachment/ghostscript.pdf) with an example of what I've described.

There are [more examples here](https://sourceforge.net/p/ghostscript/discussion/5451/thread/59701130/) in this question we've asked in GhostScript forum.

So, there is any way to compress images and keep the fonts intact with GhostScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'forum' you've posted to is SourceForge, which isn't exactly a forum. Its also used only as a mirror of the Ghostscript sources, so you won't find anyone there will answer it.

What you are asking for is simply not possible, you should read [this](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.22/VectorDevices.htm#Overview) for an explanation of why its not possible.

I see that the original file has all the fonts non embedded, so when you create a new PDF file you are again producing a file which either has no fonts embedded, or a substitute embedded. Basically that's your problem right there. If you don't embed fonts then your PDF file is, fundamentally, at the mercy of the PDF processor and whatever fonts it has available to use as substitutes for the missing font. Whatever it uses will almost certainly not be the same as what you started with, which is always going to lead to problems.

If you want your PDF files to be reliably portable, then embed the fonts. While the 'original file' may look better than the processed file, it certainly doens't look right to me.